# JMeter5.5 - Merged script failing but when run separately it is passing

Tags: jmeter

Can anyone please help me with the below issue.

I have merged my scripts , almost 7 to 8 scripts. When running the merged scripts some of the scripts are failing .
But the same scripts when run separately is passing.
Can someone help me with this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't provide "merge" scripts functionality, we cannot help you without seeing source files, knowing how the destination merged file looks like and how exactly the script "fails"

In general the options are in:

1. Launch 2 JMeter instances in GUI mode, copy the test element(s) in one instance and paste into another

   [image]
2. Reference external .jmx files using [Include Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller)
3. Move all test elements into [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and reference them using [Module Controllers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller)